# Firewall blocks websocket

Tags: firewall, node.js

Firewall kaspersky/avast blocked messages when I'm using a websocket server (socket.io on node.

What can be done?

Comment: Do you mean it is blocking incoming connections to port 8080 and 8000?

Comment: 1. with avast don't working websockets and flashsockets protocol, 2 KIS blocking outcoming messages even by AJAX multipart streaming

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your comment. Can you clarify your setup? Which system is running the browser, which system is running socket.io/node.js, and where the "firewall" is running? Also, please try temporarily disabling your firewall software (make sure you are behind a router with basic firewalling first) and see if that gets things working. Then post you config and results of that test.

Comment: Why do you have 2 anti virus programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you 100% that Avast for example blocks not only websockets, but from what I see from my Socket.IO app also xhr-polling and other stuff.

This is unacceptable, I've even tested on port 80 and it doesn't work. What an awful piece of software.

**Edit**: <strike>[this is a list of blocked ports by antiviruses](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software)</strike> (Dead 2017-07-20)

Answer (score 2):

First rule of Firewall: it can't block what it can't sense.

Does the firewall allow TLS?  If so, serve content over WSS instead of WS.

- A usual WSS client will  open a TLS connection to you ([source](https://archive.is/NNQhq#selection-93.110-105.130)) and send you this:

  ```
  GET /demo HTTP/1.1
  Upgrade: WebSocket
  Connection: Upgrade
  Host: example.com
  Origin: http://example.com
  WebSocket-Protocol: sample
  ```

  The firewall can't detect it because it is over TLS.
- A HTTP-CONNECT-WSS client will send you this:

  ```
  CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```

  The firewall sees it as yet another HTTP-CONNECT-TLS connection. ([source](https://archive.is/uj69y#selection-1677.196-1677.235))

---

Sidenote: websockets can fail due to websocket-unaware intermediary proxies **buffering connections** even if the firewall doesn't block it. The same is true of HTTP "comet" streaming.

Comment: some companies do packet inspection by installing custom root certs on their computers

Comment: Changing the protocol from "ws://" to "wss://" solved for me a similar problem with UFW (server-side firewall).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use port 443 (which is used for https) if it's possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Many ISP companies block the port 80 to prevent their customers of hosting a web servers on their home computers.

It might beyond your power to unblock the port 80 from your ISP.

Also, as far as I am concerned, Avast is not a firewall.

Comment: Right on, brother.